# Debian/Apache2 server is blocking my IP

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian

There is a Debian 6 LAMP server and from about one week I have a problem which occur randomly.
From time to time I can't access one specific domain from one specific location (IP). Our employes from other location and also the customers can access https WWW page with no problem.

Problem is only with one WWW page. Mail server, ftp server, ssh and other WWW pages on this server works OK from my location (in the time while problem with this one WWW page occur).

When the problem occur the browser (any browser) show error:

> Server not found
>
> Firefox can't find the server at kotly.com.pl.
>
> - Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox Developer Edition is permitted to access the Web.

I thought that there is a problem with DDos-Deflect script because on this location (IP) we have IP Camera which use mJpeg to show the view and if couple of people entry it could been block because of number of the request to the server, also people checking mails and there is communication between Debian server and our Windows server so the connections form one source is a lot but I've turn DDos-Deflect script off and nothing changed also if it was DDos-Deflect script it would block all server for my location(IP).

When the problem occur I also can't ping or tracert domain but without any problem I can do this with server IP. It looks like a problem with DNS but I have no idea what could be the problem.

Symptoms are like with DNS propagation for domain change.

Comment: The message `Firefox can't find the server at kotly.com.pl.` tells you that the problem is with name resolution in the network you get the error and not on the server, and not being able to `ping` or `traceroute` the DNS name but the IP is consistent with that. Check your DNS configuration.

Comment: The `dig` command has the `+trace` option which helps you debug DNS issues when your normal resolver fails.

Comment: Do you have more than one DNS Server on the Network? If so this might be something to look into. One of them has got something wrong. Might be the primary DNS has got it right, but when it is down (updates or whatever) the other one is answering and that one has got it wrong. As soon as the primary would be back on line you would not know what happened.

Comment: @Odin, I rolled back because it's too late to redact the question - your full question is in the revision history for all to see - and the domain name may well be pertinent to answering the question.  Also, Sven has embedded it in the very first comment, so it's going to be clearly visible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue brought up in this question appears to no longer be relevant. If there was anything wrong with the server, you would be seeing different symptoms. ie. if it was firewalling, you would get a timeout.

What is surprising is that you claim it only happens with one webpage. That doesn't make much sense unless you're referring to a subdomain or alternate domain. If it's the same domain, maybe the pages that are actually working are cached. Or maybe the dns issue is transient so it appears to affect random pages.

I suggest you hit the same nameservers as the ones being used when the problem is occurring and see if you can reliably reproduce the problem. Then take it up with whoever is managing the name server.